# SetText TypeError Pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, python-3.6

I recently started creating a web browser when I started to run into some problems.

I defined the function

```
self.addressbar
```

As so:

```
    self.AddressBar = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.tab)
    self.AddressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 20, 721, 31))
    self.AddressBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("AddressBar"))
```

I later defined

```
 self.Tab1Web
```

As so:

```
    self.Tab1Web = QtWebKit.QWebView(self.tab)
    self.AddressBar.setText(_fromUtf8(self.Tab1Web.url()))
    self.Tab1Web.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 70, 1171, 621))
    self.Tab1Web.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(_fromUtf8("http://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=GDbtWOjwM6WC8Qf-rI3QBA")))
    self.Tab1Web.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Tab1Web"))
```

My problem is that I get the TypeError:

```
self.AddressBar.setText(_fromUtf8(self.Tab1Web.url()))
TypeError: setText(self, object): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QUrl'
```

The problem is that I do not know how to solve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from

> http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#setText

You should pass either a python string or pyqt QString.

Try:

```
self.AddressBar.setText(self.Tab1Web.url().toString())
```

It should do the trick....

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: However, how can I get self.Addressbar to constantly change when another website is set on the Tab1View?